# How to get notification id?

Tags: android, android-notifications

i developed an basic notification example and tried to catch which notification clicked. But i couldnt.

I put an arraylist my notificaiton and pass it to reciever activity by putting extras, then try to catch but no way !

Are there anyway to catch which one cliked ?

[image]

Comment: May we see your source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `Bundle` along with PendingIntent to the next Activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Any String");
NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int uniqueInteger = //create a unique Integer        
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
NotificationCompat2.Builder mNotification = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle).setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(bundle, uniqueInteger));

mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
mNotification.setAutoCancel(true);
notifManager.notify(uniqueInteger, mNotification.build());
```

and the method `getPendingIntent()`

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Bunble bundle, int rc) { 
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, rc, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

I am using [NotificationCompat2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2) by Jake Wharton here but the answer does not depend on that.

Comment: Thank you but it is not what i need. I need to catch which notification clicked. For example if i click sender 3, it will toast sender3 clicked.

Comment: @talhakosen You can raise a Toast from _YourNextActivity.class_ with the information _sender3_ passed to the activity as a String the bundle.

Comment: Can we do that exactly for costume notification, where i used remoteview. just i need to update the specific notification from muiltiple notification .see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169367/android-update-specific-notification-from-multiple-notifications-which-have-rem