# Xamarin Android Wear: Get the currently clicked Notification ID

Tags: xamarin.android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I tried to use **PutExtra** & **GetIntExtra**, But the notification id is always overwritten by the last notification, All the notification value is the same. Please tell me how to solve it,

Thanks in advance!

```
        Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ConfirmActivity));
        actionIntent.PutExtra("NOTIFY_ID", 1);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.ic_done_white_64dp_1x,
                    this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.confirm), actionPendingIntent)
                    .Build();

        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("1111")
            .SetContentText("1111111111111111111111")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon).Extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().AddAction(action)).Build();

        var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        manager.Notify(1, notification);


        Intent actionIntent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(ConfirmActivity));
        actionIntent2.PutExtra("NOTIFY_ID", 2);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        NotificationCompat.Action action2 = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.ic_done_white_64dp_1x,
                    this.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.confirm), actionPendingIntent2)
                    .Build();

        var notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("2222")
            .SetContentText("22222222222222222222")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon).Extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().AddAction(action2)).Build();
        manager.Notify(2, notification2);

=================================

    [Activity(Label = "ConfirmActivity")]
    public class ConfirmActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Confirm);
            Intent intent = this.Intent;

            int NOTIFY_ID = intent.GetIntExtra("NOTIFY_ID", 0);  //always 2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594371/5832311). It suggested to pass a Bundle along with PendingIntent to the next Activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Any String");
NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int uniqueInteger = //create a unique Integer        
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
NotificationCompat2.Builder mNotification = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle).setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(bundle, uniqueInteger));

mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
mNotification.setAutoCancel(true);
notifManager.notify(uniqueInteger, mNotification.build());
```

Here are some related SO posts which might help:

- [How to check which notification id is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194293/how-to-check-which-notification-id-is-clicked)
- [Getting data from clicked notification in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094210/getting-data-from-clicked-notification-in-android)
- [Get the PendingIntent event when notification is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987513/get-the-pendingintent-event-when-notification-is-clicked)

Comment: Thanks, the problem I found was that I did not use a unique requestcode.